# Swiper slider not working correctly with less than 5 slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, swiper.js

So, i've created a slider with thumbnails navigation, however when it has less than 5 slides the problems start to appear.

Instead of showing just the slides that it should, it's repeating the slides to fill the container height and vertical thumbnails doesn't change slides on click, the slider works fine when have 5 or more slides.

And also when you click on the next button it flashes the vertical slider with just the slides that should display, i think there is something to do with the loop, but i want to maintain it. I'll be gratefull if someone knows how to solve this.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GabrielS0uza/zv3rk22b/2/)

```js
var sliderThumbnails = new Swiper('.slider-thumbnails', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  loop: true,
  loopedSlides: 50,
});

var sliderGallery = new Swiper('.slider-gallery', {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  loop: true,
  loopedSlides: 50,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  }
});

sliderGallery.controller.control = sliderThumbnails;
sliderThumbnails.controller.control = sliderGallery;
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.slider-thumbnails {
  float: left;
  width: calc(16% - 20px);
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 200px;
}

.slider-thumbnails .swiper-slide {
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-thumbnails .swiper-slide-active {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.slider-thumbnails .swiper-slide:hover {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.slider-gallery {
  float: right;
  width: 84%;
  height: 200px;
}

.slider-gallery .swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="swiper-container slider-thumbnails">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-container slider-gallery">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">2</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While creating 'sliderThumbnails' object, you have specified slidesPerView: 'auto' . So, thumbnails are trying to fill in the available vertical space . Change slidesPerView: 2 if there are 2 slides, 3 if there are 3 slides... Change it to 5 if there are more than or equals to 5 slides etc.

```
var sliderThumbnails = new Swiper('.slider-thumbnails', {
      direction: 'vertical',
      slidesPerView: 2,
      slideToClickedSlide: true,
      loop: true,
      loopedSlides: 50,
    });
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the number of slides will be dynamic

Comment: ya. but you can check how many slides are there and configure the "slideThumbnails" object with the appropiate number, right ?

Comment: `slidesPerView: document.querySelectorAll('.slider-thumbnails .swiper-slide').length`

Comment: I want to set the height of each slide to 20%, if i set the slidesPerView to the number of slides, it will divide by the container height, i don't want that.